# Can I use if else condition to get column string which is matched the value of another column value?

Tags: python, pandas, if-statement

I have 7 columns `[Par, Ma1, Ma2, Lay1, Lay2, Lay3, Lay4]`, which three first items `[Par, Ma1, Ma2]` contain string, and the last four items `[Lay1, Lay2, Lay3, Lay4]` contain numerical number. I use panda to read an Excel file that contains above information such as below example:

```
Par    Ma1   Ma2   Lay1   Lay2   Lay3   Lay4
N      U     V     0.1    0.2    0.7    0.8
N      T     I     0.6    0.9    0.4    0.1
N      D     L     0.4    0.7    0.3    0.5
N      E     W     0.8    0.5    0.3    0.6
N      Q     I     0.2    0.1    0.4    0.9
```

I want to get the minimum value in `[Lay1, Lay2, Lay3, Lay4]` separately, and independently while I get the minimum value, I also want to know which this value corresponding to `[Par, Ma1, Ma2]` independently as well.

For example:

```
Lay1 0.1 (minimum value), U (Ma1), V (Ma2), N (Par)
```

I try to use the "if statement" but not succeed at all.

Can I use python to perform "if else condition" to get my desirable result? If not, are there any other methods?

Comment: Have a look at the `numpy.where()` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# get the minimum values of all columns
df.min()
```

This gives the list of all the column names and its minimum value. The output will be:

```
Par       N
Ma1       D
Ma2       I
Lay1    0.1
Lay2    0.1
Lay3    0.3
Lay4    0.1
```

In order select row with minimum value in Pandas dataframe, you could do:

```
# the row which has minimum value of Lay1
df[df.Lay1 == df.Lay1.min()]
```

The output:

```
  Par Ma1 Ma2  Lay1  Lay2  Lay3  Lay4
0   N   U   V   0.1   0.2   0.7   0.8
```

For the column of Lay2:

```
df[df.Lay2 == df.Lay2.min()]
```

The output:

```
  Par Ma1 Ma2  Lay1  Lay2  Lay3  Lay4
4   N   Q   I   0.2   0.1   0.4   0.9
```

For the column of Lay3:

```
df[df.Lay3 == df.Lay3.min()]
```

The output:

```
  Par Ma1 Ma2  Lay1  Lay2  Lay3  Lay4
2   N   D   L   0.4   0.7   0.3   0.5
3   N   E   W   0.8   0.5   0.3   0.6
```

For the column of Lay4:

```
df[df.Lay4 == df.Lay4.min()]
```

The output:

```
  Par Ma1 Ma2  Lay1  Lay2  Lay3  Lay4
1   N   T   I   0.6   0.9   0.4   0.1
```

Comment: I used `df.min()` like you suggest, but I also want to show the `[Par, Mat1, Mat2]` which corresponding to the minimum value i got from `[lay1, lay2, lay3, lay4]`

Comment: Please see the extended answer for this requirement. If it is your answer, could you accept is as an answer and upvote it ? Appreciate it!

Comment: Thank you I will check and apply to my data. Really useful and appreciate it.

Comment: If it is your answer, could you accept is as an answer and upvote it ? Appreciate it!

Comment: Yes sure, However I only can accept it but can not upvote, the system doesn't let me. I am sorry for not able to upvote for you.